# Detect the Google Analytics Verifier Agent in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics

I have an MVC 3.0 website, which redirects visitors to the home page based on their UserAgent.

At the moment I have a catch-all redirection for all non-specific browsers which forwards across to a different domain - The trouble is this has made my Google Analytics verification redundant and it now tells me the code is not installed because the page Google gets on visiting my site is incorrect.

Can anyone help me detect the Google Agent so I can return a simple page which confirms the presence of Google Analytics?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the hell would you have a browser white-list?

Answer (score 0):

Just include the google analytics verification on every page.

Comment: I've looked at doing that, but I don't have control of the domain which I'm redirecting people to, so it would get their Analytics, not the one for my domain.